# Печать чека на термо принтер MacOs .Net 5 Console

Tags: c#, консоль, .net-core

Всем привет. Заранее спасибо большое за помощь.
Пытаюсь распечатать чек, использую библиотеку ESCPOS.NET https://github.com/lukevp/ESC-POS-.NET. Принтер подключен к маку по юзб.
Вопрос в том что как мне найти portName юсб порта? Пытался воспользоваться SerialPort.GetPortNames() она выводит блютусы а принтера нет.

Comment: Может там эмуляция COM порта?

Comment: Не знаю, что посоветуете?

Comment: сделать виртуальный порт и привязать к нему принтер?